# Javascript _.map() vs array.map(); why does one work here and not the other?

Tags: javascript, callback, underscore.js, higher-order-functions

Why does the reverse2 function using _.map() work, but the arr.map() doesn't work in this situation? Is there a syntax problem? I haven't been able to figure it out.

```
function reverse2(arr){
  return _.map(arr, function(val,index, arr1){return arr1.pop();});
}

console.log(reverse2([1,2,3,4,5,6]));   // logs [6,5,4,3,2,1]


function reverse3(arr){
  return arr.map(function(val,index, arr1){return arr1.pop();});
}

console.log(reverse3([1,2,3,4,5,6]));   // logs [6,5,4,undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Comment: Never ever modify an array while iterating it. Or expect anything to work like that.

Comment: The native `map` method jumps over holes. So don't delete elements from it.

Comment: looks like _.map doesn't dupe the array before passing it to the callback, like the OEM does. it has a few other non-conformities as well, but they allow a much faster operation than the native.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Array.prototype.map

This is tricky question. To explain why [Array.prototype.map](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19) behaves this way we need to check [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19). So:

1. Let *O* be the result of calling *ToObject* passing the **this** value as the argument.
2. Let *lenValue* be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of *O* with the argument "**length**".
3. Let *len* be ToUint32(lenValue).
4. If IsCallable(*callbackfn*) is **false**, throw a **TypeError** exception.
5. If *thisArg* was supplied, let *T* be *thisArg*; else let *T* be **undefined**.
6. Let *A* be a new array created as if by the expression **new Array(len)** where **Array** is the standard built-in constructor with that name and *len* is the value of *len*.
   ...

The important points here to pay attention are #2 and #6. From them it's obvious that `map` creates a new array with the **same** length as the original one.

Then another thing from the same section about method:

> ... If existing elements of the array are changed, their value as passed to callbackfn will be the value at the time map visits them; elements that are deleted after the call to **map** begins and before being visited are not visited.

And it gives the answer to your question: map will create an array of the same length but since in iteration function you are removing elements from original array (with `pop`), new array populated with only second half of the original.

#### _.map

Why Underscore [`_.map`](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L173) function behave differently? Because the implementation of it iterates over *all* items of the original array. Hence the difference.

Answer (score 3):

```
array.map

first call: [1,2,3,4,5,6], position 0 hash value '1', so pop 6.
seconde call: [1,2,3,4,5], position 1 hash value '2', so pop 5.
third call: [1,2,3,4], position 2 hash value '3', so pop 4.
fourth call: [1,2,3], position 3 hash no value, so pop nothing.
```

Comment: You don't state how this answers the question.

Comment: Its explaining why the array.map doesnt work, he could make a better introduction for ppl like you, but its ok.